# The thing on wheels in which we place stuff, luggage? Detachable from vehicles

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

The word just doesn't seem to want to get back into my brain.

I can't even put a picture of it, seeing as I don't know what to search for. Its like an extension boot, open-air, not covered. It's attached to the vehicle by a hook or something similar. It has to be open-air though. Something not as big as a trailer house.

Also, I'm getting slight hints of such a... **device** being seen in a Charlie Brown Comic?

Comment: In the U.S., it's called a *trailer.*

Comment: Isn't that like, BIG? Or can there be smaller ones too? And can that word be used for open-air types? And please, answer in the normal method, not in comments. Forces me to leave the question unanswered

Comment: A *trailer* is anything you attach to a car and tow behind it, so it can be small. But I don't think I've seen any open-air types in the U.S.

Comment: If it's attached to the vehicle, on the roof or trunk rather than towed behind on its own wheels, it could be a luggage rack or rooftop carrier.  There are general ones, plus special racks/carriers for bikes, skis, kayaks, &c.  (See e.g. Yakima or Thule companies for commercial examples.)

Comment: Are you thinking of "dolly"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the U.S., anything that's detachable and can be towed behind a car is called a *trailer*. Small ones are sometimes called *luggage trailers*.

The small ones I recall seeing on the roads have generally been closed-top. I don't know if we have any special words for open-top ones, as opposed to closed-top ones.

Comment: Yup. I'm gonna go with luggage trailers

Comment: Open topped ones might be called a "utility trailer" if it has sides, or "flatbed trailer" if there's just a small rim.  Then there are specialized ones for motorcycles, snowmobiles, &c.